# How to transfer data from a JavaScript variable to a python file in a Django project?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I'm making a recipe generator website where each ingredient is an image inside a div. When that div is clicked, it toggles to another colour. When submit is clicked, I want the ids of all the selected divs to be consolidated into one array. I'm able to achieve this using JavaScript, using the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var selectedDivs = [];

  $(".square").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");

    var divId = $(this).attr("id");
    var index = selectedDivs.indexOf(divId);

    if (index === -1) {
      selectedDivs.push(divId);
    } else {
      selectedDivs.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });

  $("#submit").click(function () {
    $("#result").text("Selected Divs: " + JSON.stringify(selectedDivs));
  });
});
```

How do I now send this data to the views.py file in my Django project, where it can become a list? Or is there a way to achieve this functionality directly in the python file itself?

I tried using AJAX but I'm not sure how to link the pages properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use AJAX to send data from your JavaScript to Django.
Here's an example.

Do you have a urls.py?
You create a URL route there

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('process_selected_divs/', views.process_selected_divs, name='process_selected_divs'),
]
```

Create a view function in your Django app's views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def process_selected_divs(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_divs = request.POST.getlist('selected_divs[]')
        # Process the selected_divs list as required
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Success'})

    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Invalid request method'})
```

Finally, add a CSRF protection for AJAX in your JavaScript file and send the data using AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Get CSRF token
  const csrf_token = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;

  var selectedDivs = [];

  $(".square").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");

    var divId = $(this).attr("id");
    var index = selectedDivs.indexOf(divId);

    if (index === -1) {
      selectedDivs.push(divId);
    } else {
      selectedDivs.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });

  $("#submit").click(function () {
    $("#result").text("Selected Divs: " + JSON.stringify(selectedDivs));

    // Send the data to the Django view
    $.ajax({
      url: '/process_selected_divs/',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token,
        selected_divs: selectedDivs
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

So when the submit button is clicked, the JavaScript sends and AJAX post request to the process_selected_divs URL, which calls the process_selected_divs view function in your views.py.

The selected_divs array is sent as part of the POST request, then the view function returns a JSON response that you can use.